# Java Illegal start of type error

Tags: java

I am getting an illegal start of type error at the first nested if statement, having looked at similar questions i understand this is usually caused by a misplaced brace, however, i cannot see one. Could anyone help?

```
public class Journey
{
    private int date;
    private double time;
    private int busNumber;
    private int journeyType;
    public static double dayCharge;
    public static final double maxDayCharge = 3.50;
    public static double weekCharge;
    public static final double maxWeekCharge = 15;
    public static double monthCharge;
    public static final double maxMonthCharge = 48;
    private int journeyId;
    private static int numberOfJourneys;
    private double costOfJourney; 

    public int getDate(){
        return date;
    }  
    public Double getTime(){
        return time;
    }
    public int getBusNumber(){
        return busNumber;
    }
    public double journeyCost(journey reqJourney){ 
        if (journeyType = 1){                      //this is where the error occurs
            if (dayCharge =< 2.50)
            {
                costOfJourney = 1;
            }
            else 
            {
                costOfJourney = maxDayCharge-dayCharge;
            }

        }
        else if (journeyType = 2)
        {
            if (dayCharge =< 1.80)
            {
                costOfJourney = 1.70;
            }
            else 
            {
                costOfJourney = maxDayCharge-dayCharge;
            }
        }
        else if (journeyType = 3)
        {
            if (dayCharge =< 1.60)
            {
                costOfJourney = 1.90;
            }
            else 
            {
                costOfJourney = maxDayCharge-dayCharge;
            }

        }          
        return costOfJourney;    
    }
    public boolean isInSequence(journey reqJourney){
        journey prevJourney = jArray.get(jArray.size()-1);
        if (prevJourney.date > reqJourney.date)
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `==` to test equality. `=` is the assignment operator.

Oracle has good [tutorial docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) explaining Java operators.

On a related note, there's also an important distinction between `Object.equals()` and `==` which is covered in detail in other Stack Overflow questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus). However, when comparing primitive types like you're doing, `==` is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
 if (journeyType == 1){
```

Expression in if block should always results in boolean value (either true (or) false).